# Bootstrap navbar dropdown not functioning consistently?

Tags: bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I can't get the Bootstrap navbar dropdown to work consistently.

- On first page load it works
- If I click a nav link, when the new page loads the dropdown might drop down or might not do anything.
- If after the dropdown fails I click some other link that may fix it but more likely not.
- If I refresh the page, the dropdown will consistently work.

I'm working on a Rails 6 app with Bootstrap 4.5. I pretty much copied the example navbar code from their docs, filled out the link paths and adjusted the id. (I also removed the toggler trying to troubleshoot)

If it helps I've been having similar issues with the Bootstrap collapse functionality not working consistently.

*views/layouts/application.html.haml:*

```
%html
  %head
    %link{:crossorigin => "anonymous", :href => "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", :integrity => "sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2", :rel => "stylesheet"}/


    %title
      @title

    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag

  %body
    .container
      = render "layouts/nav"
      %p.notice.hide= notice
      %p.alert.hide= alert
      = yield
      .footer

    %script{:crossorigin => "anonymous", :integrity => "sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj", :src => "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"}
    %script{:crossorigin => "anonymous", :integrity => "sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx", :src => "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"}
```

*views/layouts/_nav.html/haml:*

```
%nav.navbar.navbar-expand.navbar-light.bg-light
  %a.navbar-brand{:href => root_path} Home
  #navbarSupportedContent
    %ul.navbar-nav.mr-auto
      %li.nav-item.dropdown
        %a#navbarDropdownOne.nav-link.dropdown-toggle{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "#", :role => "button"}
          Planner
        .dropdown-menu{"aria-labelledby" => "navbarDropdownOne"}
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => events_path} Events
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => setups_path} Setups
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => event_sessions_path} Event Sessions
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => setup_answers_path} Setup Answers

      %li.nav-item.dropdown
        %a#navbarDropdownTwo.nav-link.dropdown-toggle{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "#", :role => "button"}
          Supplier
        .dropdown-menu{"aria-labelledby" => "navbarDropdownTwo"}
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => setup_categories_path} Setup Categories
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => questions_path} Questions
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => multiple_choices_path} Multiple Choices
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => template_items_path} Template Items
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => template_answers_path} Template Answers
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => items_path} Items

      %li.nav-item.dropdown
        %a#navbarDropdownThree.nav-link.dropdown-toggle{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "#", :role => "button"}
          Admin
        .dropdown-menu{"aria-labelledby" => "navbarDropdownThree"}
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => user_path(current_user)} Your Account
          %a.dropdown-item{:href => users_path} Users
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution to this by accident while I was doing an unrelated tutorial. (Using react w/rails)

Rather than follow the instructions exactly from the [bootstrap 4.5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/), in terminal I ran:

```
yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

Then in *app/javascript/packs/application.js* I have:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require('bootstrap')
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap'
```

I removed the stylesheet and script links and instead have "stylesheet_pack_tag" for *app/views/layouts/application.html.haml*:

```
%html
  %head
    %title
      = @title

    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag

    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = stylesheet_pack_tag 'application'


  %body
    .container
      - if current_user
        = render "layouts/nav"
      %p.notice.hide= notice
      %p.alert.hide= alert
      = yield
      .footer
```